# Why are fluctations of the inflaton field quantum?

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation

In studying inflation one writes $\phi(\vec x, t)=\phi_0(t)+\delta \phi (\vec x, t)$

where $\delta \phi (\vec x, t)$ are quantum fluctuations that can be written in terms of creation and annihilation operators. Why are they quantum?

Why didn't I write $\delta \phi (\vec x, t)$ as classical?

Comment: What do you mean by "writing $\delta\phi$ as classical"? I don't know about inflation but this looks like the standard split of a field into its vacuum expectation value and "fluctuation" around it in QFT - what exactly is $\phi_0$ that you see a chance for this to be a classical situation?

Comment: Yes is a you say. But the fact is that I was asking why can't  we take, a priori, $\phi$ classical, i.e. without making quantization. So the beginning question could be why are we considering QFT? I know that this is the correct way, but why can't we have classical random fluctations?

Comment: they cannot explain the homogeneity of the cosmic microwave backgroound, the relativistic  light cones are such that the whole universe cannot be causally connected so as to get thermodyamic homogenisation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The physics reason for introducing quantum mechanics at the beginning of the universe is because classical General Relativity has a singularity at the beginning of time.As all singularities of classical physics disappear when the quantum mechanical underlying nature is calculated, it is rational to expect that this will be the solution for the original Big Bang singularity. It is expected that a theory unifying all [four forces](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html) will be quantum mechanical.

The inflaton field is an answer to the observational problem that the [cosmic microwave background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Cmbr.svg) is highly homogeneous. This homogeneity cannot be [modeled](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/cosmo.html#c5) with classical thermodynamics, as there is no way for the early universe to homogenize by particle interactions. The [effective quantization during the inflationary period](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/inflat.html)

[image: inflation]

homogenizes the primordial soup, the quantum fluctuation becoming the seeds of the small inhomogeneities observed in the CMB.

> If [the universe inflated](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/cosmo.html#c6) by 20 to 30 orders of magnitude, then the properties of an extremely tiny volume which could have been considered to be intimately connected were spread over the whole of the known universe today, contributing both extreme flatness and the extremely isotropic nature of the cosmic background radiation.

This cannot be done with classical fields.

Comment: You wrote that we can't do this by classical fields. Ok, and I believe it. But I still don't see when we can use the fact that the fluctuations are quantistic...

Comment: By construction of quantum mechanical theories there are fluctuations, remember the Heisenberg uncertainty? It is inherent in the operator structure of quantum mechanical theories. The fluctuations of the inflaton field are seen/explain the seeds of clusters of galaxies seen in the CMB plot in the wiki link I mention above.

Comment: Quantum theory is used in the Big Bang current model up to the  creation of the protons ,  and then nuclear physics, which also uses quantum theory, takes over.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_(cosmology)#/media/File:History_of_the_Universe.svg

Comment: I found this https://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.0087.pdf
Why do cosmological perturbations look classical to us?